# SpringBoot- Table not getting created while application startUp

Tags: hibernate, web-services, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and trying to write a small webservice to perform CRUD with Spring Boot and hibernate . I am facing a issue where i am not able to create table as per the entity and configuration defined when i am starting the application. Below is the configuration that i have defined.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@test12.test.test.test.net:7777/TEST
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

And i have my domain class something like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLASS_DETAIL")
public class ClassDetail{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long classID;
private String className;
private String classOwnername;
private int classId;

with getter and setter ..
}
```

When i am starting the application application is getting started but i am not able to see the created table in my defined schema.
Any mistake i am doing in terms of configuration or missing anything ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue resolved.The problem was with my package structure that i defined in the pom.xml with my project Name.

```
<groupId>com.springboot.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringRESTExample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

After giving the right folder structure for domain and the main spring boot class.I was able to create the table structure.